# Error : 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, string, typeerror

i am changing a cpp code to python.
but python code dosent run.
This is my python code :

```
n,k=input().split()
s=input()
l = len(s)
ans = 0
k=int(k)
for i in range(l):
    ans += max(ord(s[i]) - ord('a'), ord('z') - ord(s[i]))
if (ans < k):
    print("-1")
for i in range(l):
    if ((ord(s[i]) - ord('a')) > (ord('z') - ord(s[i]))):
        now = ord(s[i]) - ord('a')
        if (now >= k) :
            s[i] -= k
            k=0
        else :
            s[i] = chr(ord('a'))
            k -= now
    else:
        now = ord('z') - ord(s[i])
        if (now >= k):
            s[i] =chr(ord(s[i])+ k)
            k=0
        else:
            s[i] ='z'
            k -= now
print(s)
```

and i get this error :

```
...line 22, in <module>
    s[i] =chr(ord(s[i])+ k)
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: error solved .Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- string are immutable in python
- You are trying to change a string
- I would recommend you to convert your string to a list by doing this:

  ```
  string = "abs"
  string_list = list(string)
  print(string_list)
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  ['a', 'b', 's']
  ```
- Now operate on this list because list is mutable `string_list`
- In your code you have to convert the variable `s` to a list and then operate on it